# WebSocket over an encrypted TLS connection (wss)

Tags: amazon-web-services, codenameone

I am trying to implement an AWS API Gateway WebSocket server to connect with my CODENAME Websocket. I am getting the exception "java.io.IOException: Attempt to send a message while the socket is not open. CLOSED"

I want to know if the CODENAME WebSocket implementation does not work with was protocol or if it is related to the $connect route implementation.

---

```
final WebSocket sock = new WebSocket("wss://xxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/development/") {

                @Override
                protected void onOpen() {
                    System.out.println("In onOpen");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onMessage(String message) {
                    System.out.println("Received message "+message);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onError(Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("in onError");
                }

                @Override
                protected void onMessage(byte[] message) {
                    // Received a binary message
                }

            };
            //.autoReconnect(5000); // Automatically reconnect if connection fails or server disconnects
            // Attempts every 5 seconds until successful

            sock.connect();
}
```

---

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: Update: I've resolved the issue I was facing with the AWS API Gateway WebSocket server and the CODENAME WebSocket. The problem was related to a timing issue in my implementation, where I needed to ensure a sufficient delay before sending a message. This allowed time for the WebSocket connection to fully establish and open, thereby resolving the 'java.io.IOException: Attempt to send a message while the socket is not open. CLOSED' exception.

Comment: I'd also like to add that using AWS API Gateway in conjunction with Lambda functions has proven to be a great option for implementing a WebSocket server. The flexibility, scalability, and ease of integration offered by these AWS services have significantly enhanced my project's capabilities. I highly recommend this approach to anyone looking to implement a WebSocket server.